# INVALID SYNTAX ERROR for 'else' statement in python

Tags: python, syntax-error, if-statement

I am trying to write a quicksort program in python, however I'm getting an `invalid syntax error at else statement` in the second last line below:

```
import random

n=int(raw_input("Enter the size of the list: ")) # size of the list
intlist = [0]*n
for num in range(n):
    intlist[num]=random.randint(0,10*n)

pivot=random.choice(intlist)
list_1=[] # list of elements smaller than pivot
list_2=[] # list of elements greater than pivot

for num in range(n):
    if num<=pivot:
        list_1.append(num)
    else
        list_2.append(num)
```

This is not a complete program as I am still writing.

Comment: You probably got a -1 because this is a bit of a rookie mistake (I wasn't the one who did it...). Your Stack Overflow karma won't get you chicks, jobs, or easy entry into heaven. I wouldn't let it bug you too much.

Comment: -1: because the missing ":" is pointed at directly by the Python interpreter.  It shows the line and the position on the line where the problem occurred.  Rather than read the error message, it appears that you posted your homework here.

Comment: S. Lott: As I said I am just starting, I have written in question that its an error at else statement, however I didn't know that we need ":" after else or elif etc. You are going too far ahead and judgmental.

Comment: @Harpreet: It's in the tutorial.  It's in the language reference.  It's in every example here on Stack Overflow.  The colon is hard to miss.  Further, you don't seem to have used any resources except stack overflow.  That makes the question particularly bad and not useful for other people.  The question does not show clear or careful thinking or demonstrate anything useful or interesting.  Yes, it's a judgement.  I am making that judgement.  And -- because you are new -- I'm explaining that judgement.  I **am** being judgemental.  That's what voting is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a colon after the `else` so that it looks like `else:`. and pick up a good tutorial ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a ':' after "else".